# JAVA Spring Boot - existsByColumne1AndNotColumn2 Repository query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Java Spring Boot where I want to create default query to find if a user already exists with the given mobile number and not with the given user id. A raw query is this

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE mobile = "9898989898" AND user_id != 123
```

I did found that to check with single column whether the data is exist in that column or not, we can do something like this in Repository class

```
Boolean ExistWithMobile(String mobile)
```

This will return true or false if row found with the given mobile number.

The same way I want query similar to above, but this is not working

```
Boolean existsByMobileAndNotUserId(String mobile, Long userId);
```

This should return true or false whether this phone number is available with Other userId

I know how can I work with raw queries, as I already mention that in starting of the question, but I want something like this direct way of query, without raw query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about existsByMobileAndUserIdIsNot(String mobile, Long userId) ?

Comment: @bean This is what I wanted.. Thanks for the answer! Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wanna use native sql query, you could use HQL instead.

in your case:

```
@Query("from User u Where u.mobile = :mob and u.id != :id")
Optional<User> findUserByMobile(@Param("mob") String mobile, @Param("id") long id)
```

when you call :

```
Optional<User> user = repo.findUserByMobile(mobile, uid);
if( user.isPresent() ) { ... }
```

here is doc of @Query in spring data :
[Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Good luck